# Flyspell not reading the complete word - FRENCH LANGUAGE

Tags: flyspell, ispell

I am using flyspell for the first time.
For word with "^" inside, it looks like they are read as two separate words.

For example, below, the word "maître" is underlined, and the word proposed start with "t"

[image]

And there

[image]

I understood from my first research on the web, that it might come from utf-8 not set for ispell.
I tried to change the value of `ispell-encoding8-command` initially set to `--encoding=` :

```
(setq ispell-encoding8-command "--encoding=utf-8" )
```

but it did not work

Ispell : 3.1.20
Aspell : 0.60.8

Comment: Can't reproduce this. `emacs -q`, opened a new text-mode buffer, `M-x ispell-change-dictionary RET fr_FR RET`. Then I type in `Ce que less main de Dieu dans l'immensité sèment ? Est-on maître d'aimer ? pourquoi deux êtres s'aiment,` and check the buffer with `M-x flyspell-buffer RET`. It only highlights the error I've done on purpose to see if it is working at `less`.

Comment: You are right, I was using another dictionnary `francais` which might not be complete enough. The `fr_FR` works well. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the dictionnary of ispell like @Hubisan said

`M-x ispell-change-dictionnary RET fr_FR RET`

Comment: There is a package called `auto-dictionary` (automatic dictionary switcher for flyspell) which comes in handy.